# Oracle Database connectivity issue with C# and running fine with Delphi-7

Tags: c#

The scenario is-
Delphi-7 is installed on my PC with ODAC, and my application is compiled by using ORA.dcu and is running on client's PC without installing Oracle Client on that PC. My C# application is using oracle-client.dll and running fine on my PC and one of my Client PC where I installed Oracle Client but it is not running on the PC where Oracle Client is not installed. This is not feasible solution to install Oracle Client on each client's PC.

Kindly suggest why Oracle client is required for C# exe on Client PC whereas Oracle Client is not required with Delphi-7 exe?

Can I use another library with C#?

Comment: Are you using ODAC from Devart? Anyway, you'll need [this](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/)

Comment: It's not clear what dependencies your c# app has. You should explain in more detail what dependencies your c# app has.

Comment: Yes , with Delphi I used Devart..

Comment: I'm not sure why we are talking about devart and Delphi. The question is 100% about your c# program.

Comment: Hi David, I want to know about Delphi code as well because the code was written by my seniors 10 years ago. You are correct that I want solution for the C# code